# chronosys: at the beginning and at the end of the year

Tags: chronosys

I am wondering in [chronosys](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) is there a way to put two events in a year? I also want to remove the arrow at the end

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The Journey}{Ph.D. in chronological order}

\chronoperiodecoloralternation{orange, cyan, green, green}
\startchronology[startyear=2018, stopyear=2024, dates=false,arrowcolor=green,stopdate=false]
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2018}{Started Ph.D.}
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2019}{Started thesis}
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2021}{Preliminary exam}
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2022}{Thesis result!}
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2023}{Qualifying exam} % this was done at the beginning of the 2023
\chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2023}{Defence}  % I want this to be at the end of 2023

\chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2018}{2019}{}
\chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2019}{2022}{}
\chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2022}{2023}{}
\chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2023}{2024}{}

\stopchronology

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For (1) you can just specify specific dates for events, I think. See the documentation for details. (2) is not really doable, unless it is supported out-of-the-box. Indeed, customisation is notoriously un-doable. You can contact the author asking for a custom version, if the feature isn't supported. Or you can use something more configurable than `chronosys`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Edited to use `phantom` key, which is designed to support this kind of style. Requires `chronos` no earlier than svn rev 9903.

**Note that `chronos` is experimental and rather buggy.** The linked version is the result of a rewrite of code previously posted here, together with some other code.

## *Caveat emptor*

You could try [chronos](https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos), though it is not on CTAN (yet?). The code below includes your original MWE for comparison followed by a `chronos` version. `showframe` is used to show that `chronosys` produces a timeline which protrudes into the margin, though no warning seems to be produced on the terminal.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701743/ i gwestiwn Node.JS: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699881/
% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos
\usepackage{chronos}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The Journey}{Ph.D. in chronological order}
  \chronoperiodecoloralternation{orange, cyan, green, green}
  \startchronology[startyear=2018, stopyear=2024, dates=false,arrowcolor=green,stopdate=false]
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2018}{Started Ph.D.}
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2019}{Started thesis}
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2021}{Preliminary exam}
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2022}{Thesis result!}
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2023}{Qualifying exam} % this was done at the beginning of the 2023
  \chronoevent[textstyle=\tiny]{2023}{Defence}  % I want this to be at the end of 2023
  \chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2018}{2019}{}
  \chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2019}{2022}{}
  \chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2022}{2023}{}
  \chronoperiode[startdate=false, stopdate=false]{2023}{2024}{}
  \stopchronology
\end{frame}

\centering

\begin{chronos}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701743/ i gwestiwn Node.JS: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699881/
  % https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos **min svn rev 9903**
  [
    lines on line=10pt,% line height
    timeline={%
      dates=2018:2024,
      width=.9\linewidth,
      timeline line={-,shorten >=0pt},% because lines on line has an arrow
      timeline margin'=0pt,
    },
    outer border'=0pt,
    without eras,
    text tags+={font=\sffamily},
    every event below,
    event={%
      only years,
      colour=black,
      text font=\tiny,  
    },
    period={%
      colours below={orange,cyan,green,green},
      phantom,
      only years,
    },
  ]
  % these **must** be named, even though they are invisible and detached
  \chronosperiod{dates=2018:2019,name={n1}}
  \chronosperiod{dates=2019:2022,name={n2}}
  \chronosperiod{dates=2022:2023,name={n3}}
  \chronosperiod{dates=2023:2024,name={n4}}
  \chronosevent{date=2018,name={Started Ph.D.},}
  \chronosevent{date=2019,name={Started thesis},}
  \chronosevent{date=2021,name={Preliminary exam},}
  \chronosevent{date=2022,name={Thesis result!},}
  \chronosevent{date=2023-01-01,name={Qualifying exam},} % this was done at the beginning of the 2023
  \chronosevent{date=2023-12-31,name={Defence},}  % I want this to be at the end of 2023
  \chronosmaintitle{name content=The Journey,label={[font=\sffamily]right:PhD in chronological order},at=Started PhD |- chronos head,anchor=south west,yshift=10pt,font=\sffamily,draw }
\end{chronos}

\end{document}
```

`chronos` has no problem putting two events at different points in the year and readily supports either an arrow or no arrow. While the original answer used a version in which creating periods (or events or lives) which didn't have text boxes required a bit of trickery, the current version provides `phantom`. Unlike my original answer, which involved creating invisible text boxes and not connecting them to anything, `phantom` means they are not constructed at all. This is more efficient, should be more reliable and is (hopefully) more straightforward to use.

[image: chronosys result (above); chronos below; outer lines indicate page layout]